# SwiftUI .fileExporter() with a .csv file in the View

Tags: csv, swiftui

I would like to use .fileExporter() to download a .csv file in SwiftUI.  (Or a shareSheet)

I am using a MVVM setup.

I first create and save the .cvs in the ViewModel.

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data:Data? = nil
      
    let fileName = "data"
    let folderName = "my_folder"
      
    init(){
       
        saveCSVFile()
        
        getCVFile()
        
    }
```

Here are the save/create functions.

```
func saveCSVFile() {
    
    guard
        let file = createCSVData(),
        let path = getPathForCSV(name: fileName)
    
    else {
        print("error")
        return  
    }
     
    do {
        try file.write(to: path)
        return 
        
    } catch let error {
        return   
    }
    
}  

func saveCSVFile()  {
    
    guard
        let file = createCSVData(),
        let path = getPathForCSV(name: fileName)
    
    else {
        print("error")
        return 
    }
     
    do {
        try file.write(to: path)
        return 
        
    } catch let error {
        print ("error saving \(error)")
        return  
        
    }
    
}
 
func getPathForCSV (name: String) -> URL? {

    guard
        let path = FileManager
            .default
            .urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            .first?
            .appendingPathComponent(folderName)
            .appendingPathComponent("\(name).csv") else {
        print("path error")
        return nil
    }
     
    return path

 }
```

All good so far.  File is created and where it needs to be.

Now I try to retrieve the file.

```
func getCSVFile() {
     
    guard let path = getPathForCSV(name: fileName)
    
    else { 
        print("getCSVFile not found")
        return
    } 
    
    // get the file
    
    do {
        
        let d = try Data(contentsOf: path)
        
        self.data = d       // pass value to @Published var data
        
        return
        
    } catch let error { }
     
}
```

Now I use to publish the data to the view.

```
@Published var data:Data? = nil
```

But it is not working in the View with something like this.

```
.fileExporter(
        isPresented: $isExporting,
        document: vm.data,
        contentType: UTType.commaSeparatedText,
        defaultFilename: "DownloadData.csv"
    )
```

This tosses a "No exact matches in call to instance method 'fileExporter'" error.

If I change to a ShareSheet I just get a blank page.

I suspect it is the way the data is formatted when I read it back and try to give to the View?

Thank you very much for your ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation error doesn't have anything to do with the way the data is formatted -- it's just that there isn't a signature for `fileExporter` that matches what you're providing. In particular, you're trying to just pass `Data` directly to `document`, which exports a `FileDocument` or `ReferenceFileDocument`.

Here's an example, with some borrowed/modified code from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-export-files-using-fileexporter:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var isExporting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Export") {
                isExporting = true
            }
            .fileExporter(isPresented: $isExporting, document: CSVFile(initialText: "Item 1, Item2, Item3"), contentType: UTType.commaSeparatedText) { result in
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CSVFile: FileDocument {
    // tell the system we support only plain text
    static var readableContentTypes = [UTType.commaSeparatedText]
    static var writableContentTypes = [UTType.commaSeparatedText]

    // by default our document is empty
    var text = ""

    // a simple initializer that creates new, empty documents
    init(initialText: String = "") {
        text = initialText
    }

    // this initializer loads data that has been saved previously
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            text = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        }
    }

    // this will be called when the system wants to write our data to disk
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = Data(text.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that article. So how would i pass my @Published var data:Data? = nil into  this CSVFile: FileDocument{}   I am reading the Data from the file.  i have been stuck for days. very confused. thank you so much!

Comment: and i am happy to change to a shareSheet if that is eaiser. I just need to download the data.cvs file so they can get the data into Excel.

Comment: So where is the actual problem in your code? I was under the impression that the compilation error was the issue.

Comment: i wish i knew.  square peg and round hole. I can create and save file to directory fine. just need to find a way to read it back so the user can download it?

Comment: So the question is just how to read a file? You haven't included the code for `getPathForCSV`, so it's impossible to say whether the paths match in your read/write methods.

Comment: updated. it is finding the file and not returning any errors.   thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of reading the file in as a string (not Data) and then I could use @jnpdx solution of CSVFile: FileDocument. Or the ShareView approach.

```
 @Published var cvs_sting:String?

 let d = try String(contentsOf: path)
          
 self.cvs_sting = d
```

And in the view

```
    .fileExporter(isPresented: $isExporting,
                  document: CSVFile(initialText: vm.cvs_sting ?? "error occured"),
                  contentType: .plainText) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let url):
            print("Saved to \(url)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```